# JavaScript para um fluxograma

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou montando um fluxograma na web e preciso de um JavaScript para fazer funcionar o fluxograma. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia onde posso encontrar um JavaScript FREE de Fluxograma ? 
Precisaria de algo como isso:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html

Comment: Você quer uma ferramenta javascript para desenhar o fluxograma?

Comment: Uma dica **java** não é **javascript**.

Comment: Explica melhor a tua dúvida, pois no mesmo link que tu postou tem um tutorial pra fazer o fluxoagrama com o GoJS.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade a questão é que naquele tutorial o JS é pago..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você apenas quer uma alternativa pra criar fluxoagramas, o Google possui a biblioteca [Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) e nela há a opção 
[Organization Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#overview).

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ["orgchart"]
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
        data.addRows([
          [{
              v: 'Mike',
              f: 'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'
            },
            '', 'The President'
          ],
          [{
              v: 'Jim',
              f: 'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'
            },
            'Mike', 'VP'
          ],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]);

        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        chart.draw(data, {
          allowHtml: true
        });
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```